# NoMethodError in BlogsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

I've spent the last three hours trying to find a solution to this and checked everything I could find here on StackOverflow but no go.

I am specifically getting this error: `"undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass"`

And the application trace gives me this: `app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:7:in`create'`

I think it has something to do with how I am passing the params but I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's my Controller code:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @blogs = Blog.all
end

def new
  @blog_entry = Blog.new
end

def create
  Blog.create(title: params[:blogs][:title], content: params[:blogs][:content])
  redirect_to action: 'index'
end
end
```

Here's my new.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for @blog_entry, as: :post, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  Title: </br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %> <br />
  Content: <br />
  <%= f.text_area :content %> <br />
  <%= f.submit "Publish", class: "btn btn-primary" %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Here's the relevant log file:

```
Started POST "/blogs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-12 21:54:48 -0700
Processing by BlogsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"cSGH7PgbbFHSSEPV3pJ2LP6V1GvUN10RHRfUDTUXou4=", "post"=>{"title"=>"first      entry 5", "content"=>"new entry"}, "commit"=>"Publish"}
   [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "blogs" ("content", "created_at", "title",     "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["content", nil], ["created_at", Thu, 13 Jun 2013     04:54:48 UTC +00:00], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 13 Jun 2013 04:54:48 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (3.2ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/blogs
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
```

Hopefully someone has an idea. Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
def create
  Blog.create(params[:blog])
  redirect_to action: 'index'
end
```

let me know if it's not. I'll try to revise my answer, and paste please the full error trace here in case it's not working. The console logs too, as you initialize `@blog_entry` in the new action you might need to create blog with `Blog.create(params[:blog_entry])`

**EDIT**

from console    `"post"=>{"title"=>"first      entry 5", "content"=>"new entry"}`

means you need to create a blog entry with: `Blog.create(params[:post])`

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not working either. I'm not getting any errors but it is creating a record with nil values for the fields.

Comment: I have also tried using Blog.create(params{:blog_entry]) with the same nil results.

Comment: the console logs please, at the point where you press the submit button

Comment: in the terminal where you started the rails server with rails s or passenger start.. there are the server logs, when you do some action on your app it shows you the logs, what is happening inside of your app. When you submit a blog, you must see something like `Started POST "/blogs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-13 07:46:37 +0300
Processing by BlogsController#create as HTML` this is just an exemple

Comment: and what version of rails you use?

Comment: updated my answer, but again, your params are nil when they are saving to a record.

Comment: thanks that works, but I don't understand why the key in params hash is :post. Did I set up the form_for helper wrong?

Comment: you have `as: :post` in the form